# Platform with type "Windows_NT" and architecture "ia32" is not supported by @aws-amplify/cli.}

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

My first AWS project, I was trying to use amplify cli, I used `npm i -g @aws-amplify/cli@4.24` and amplify configure worked perfectly.
Some way down the project when trying amplify push I got an error which had a fix that said to update cli to latest.
When I reinstalled the cli using `npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli`, the output of amplify configure is `PS C:\Users\abdul> amplify configure Platform with type "Windows_NT" and architecture "ia32" is not supported by @aws-amplify/cli.}`
I even tried `npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli --unsafe-perm=true # install latest amplify-CLI` to no avail.
Can someone explain to me why the newer versions seem not to support Windows?
keeping in mind it worked till PUSH on v4.2

Answer (score 3):

Update to node v18.
Then you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/start/install/ and install it by curl. Please see below screenshot.

[image]